# How to set focus to an object(textbox) in main form from another form (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus, controls

I tried everything I know. The trouble must be that my textbox is in a groupbox. I have a Mainform from which I move to another form. When I return to Mainform, I want a particular object to be focused. How is this done?
Here's my code in my Mainform.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Form1 frm = new Form1();
         frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

now this is how i return back to my Mainform from Form1.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

I have textBox1 in Mainform. How to set focus to textBox1 when quitting Form1 and entering Mainform. I tried `textBox1.Focus();` and `this.ActiveControl = this.textBox1;` under Mainform `Load`, `Show`, `Activated` and `Enter` events. Still didn't work. I tried creating a public method and call it under the exit button of Form1. Like this.

In Mainform,

```
    public void textBox1Focus()
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

And then in Form1,

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Mainform frm = new Mainform();
        frm.textBox1Focus();
    }
```

Which still didn't work. My textBox1 is in a groupbox. Could that be the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand how the code that you've shown even compiles. You're calling `textBox1Focus()` from inside a method that's defined in the `Form1` class, which as best I can understand, doesn't include a definition for `textBox1Focus`. That method is only defined in the `Mainform` class.

And no, the text box being placed in a group box is not preventing it from getting the focus. There's something else wrong with your code. It's hard to tell; I feel like I'm looking at a sunset through Venetian blinds, rather than through a large picture window.

Anyway, I suspect there's a simpler solution. Just set the focus to the textbox control at the end of the `button1_Click` method. The `ShowDialog` method is a blocking call, which means execution won't continue until after the user closes the second form. When that happens, execution will continue with the next line of code, which will set the focus to the textbox control.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form1 frm = new Form1();
     frm.ShowDialog();
     this.textBox1.Select();
}
```

Comment: Yes u nailed it. Your code worked successfully and I'm thankful for that!

Regrading the error in m code, sorry for that. That was a minor mistake. I edited and fixed it in my question. But to tell you, I had it done properly in my actual code (otherwise error would have been shown). Still the method din quite work. But your trick does the trick :)

Comment: @nawfal: No problem; glad I could help. For future reference, it's much easier to just copy and paste your code into your question. That cuts down on typos that might creep in there. It's hard enough for us to debug your code as it is because we can't see it in context. You can't just ignore syntax errors, because often times those are the actual problem!

Comment: I actually din copy paste my code just to make the code look saner and simpler. But it backfired ;-)